# Отловить нажатие кнопки

Tags: c#, события

Добрый день коллеги!

Как узнать нажималась кнопка или нет на системном блоке для выключение компьютера.

Спасибо, с уважением.

Answer (score 1):

Копайте в сторону WM_QUERYENDSESSION, может что-то и найдете в гугле. [Здесь описание завершения работы WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa376882(v=vs.85).aspx) Но, я думаю, что здесь нужен драйвер, чтобы получить информацию от железа, С# вам врядли поможет.

Comment: WM_QUERYENDSESSION это результат сообщения отправленный от приложения.

Мне бы вот немного по раньше. Просто есть такая ситуация, если пользователь перейдет в режим Lock то при нажатии кнопки на системном блоке нечего не происходит. Мне бы узнать, что именно в этом случаи происходит и вычислить нажатии кнопки. Задача не простая, но куда копать уже запутался.

Comment: Уже не на одном форуме задал вопрос. Не кто пока что не направил правильно куда копать. Потоки Windows нечего так и не дали.